# no se respetan los valores al agregar un objeto dentro de otro objeto que esta dentro de otro objeto en listas de kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Tratare de ser práctico

Tengo una objeto para almacenar un grupo de tickets

```
data class TicketProvisional(
    val id_producto: Long,
    var cantidad: Int,
    val nombre_producto: String,
    val precio: Int,
    val id_categoria: Long,
    val item: MutableList<TicketProvisionalItem>
)
```

Que almacena los Items de los ticket

```
data class TicketProvisionalItem(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int,
    val id_producto: Long,
    val nombre_producto: String,
    val precio: Int,
    val id_categoria: Long,
    val tipo: String,
    var mp_ni_prov: String = "",
    var mp_prov: String = "",
    var mp_extra: String = "",
    var mp_extra_cantidad: String = "",
){
    @Ignore var mp_ni: List<MateriaPrimaNoInventariable> = listOf()
    @Ignore var mp: List<MateriaPrima> = listOf()
    @Ignore var mp_extra_x: List<MateriaPrima> = listOf()
}
```

Que almacena la materia prima de cada Item

```
data class MateriaPrima(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Long,
    val nombre: String,
    val extra: String? = null,
    val imagen: String? = null,
    val precio: Int? = null,
    var cantidad_extra: Int? = null
)
```

Asingo los valores por medio de Room y todo perfecto, excepto el campo CANTIDAD_EXTRA de MateriaPrima que se asigna el final.

```
        val mp_extra_str = if (producto.mp_extra.isNotEmpty()) producto.mp_extra.split(",").map { it.toLong() } else listOf()
        val cant = if (producto.mp_extra_cantidad.isNotEmpty()) producto.mp_extra_cantidad.split(",").map { it.toInt() } else listOf()

        producto.mp_ni = if (mp_ni_str.isNotEmpty()) mp_ni.filter { it.id in mp_ni_str } else listOf()
        producto.mp = if (mp_str.isNotEmpty()) mp.filter { it.id in mp_str } else listOf()
        producto.mp_extra_x = if (mp_extra_str.isNotEmpty()) mp.filter{ it.id in mp_extra_str } else listOf()

        if(mp_extra_str.isNotEmpty()){
            mp_extra_str.forEachIndexed { index, l ->
                producto.mp_extra_x.find { it.id == l }?.let{
                    it.cantidad_extra = cant[index]
                    total += (it.precio!! * it.cantidad_extra!!)
                }
            }
        }
```

He echo muchas pruebas antes de agregar los objetos a "TicketProvisional" y todos los datos están correctos, también la cantidad de la materia prima

El problema existe cuando agrego el "Producto" que incluye la "MateriaPrima" al "TicketProvisional"

Dentro del bucle de "Productos", despues de agregar el Item me arroja datos reales, al final del bucle al revisar el "TicketProvisional" en este momento me cambia el valor de CANTIDAD_EXTRA al ultimo valor agregado de todas las MP y siempre toma el ultimo valor de la MP agregada.

```
        tp.find { it.id_producto == producto.id_producto }?.let {
            it.cantidad += 1
            it.item.add(producto)
        } ?: run {
            tp.add(
                TicketProvisional(
                    producto.id_producto,
                    1,
                    producto.tipo + " " + producto.nombre_producto,
                    producto.precio,
                    producto.id_categoria,
                    mutableListOf(producto)
                )
            )
        }
```

Como información, si existe el "TicketProvisional", que es un grupo de productos, suma 1 a la cantidad y agrega el "Producto", sino existe agrega un "Ticket" más un "Item" junto con el "Producto", en cualquiera de las dos opciones pasa lo mismo

Por ejemplo los datos que debería contener

```
2022-04-12 03:34:09.366 18769-18769/com.example.tpv I/REAL: Producto ID:1 : tocino : 1
2022-04-12 03:34:09.366 18769-18769/com.example.tpv I/REAL: Producto ID:1 : boneless : 2
2022-04-12 03:34:09.366 18769-18769/com.example.tpv I/REAL: Producto ID:4 : salchicha p/ asar : 1
2022-04-12 03:34:09.366 18769-18769/com.example.tpv I/REAL: Producto ID:4 : tocino : 2
2022-04-12 03:34:09.366 18769-18769/com.example.tpv I/REAL: Producto ID:3 : salchicha p/ asar : 3
2022-04-12 03:34:09.366 18769-18769/com.example.tpv I/REAL: Producto ID:3 : tocino : 3
2022-04-12 03:34:09.366 18769-18769/com.example.tpv I/REAL: Producto ID:3 : boneless : 3
```

Y me arroja los siguientes datos

```
2022-04-12 03:34:09.366 18769-18769/com.example.tpv I/ERROR: Producto ID:1 : tocino : 3
2022-04-12 03:34:09.366 18769-18769/com.example.tpv I/ERROR: Producto ID:1 : boneless : 3
2022-04-12 03:34:09.366 18769-18769/com.example.tpv I/ERROR: Producto ID:4 : salchicha p/ asar : 3
2022-04-12 03:34:09.366 18769-18769/com.example.tpv I/ERROR: Producto ID:4 : tocino : 3
2022-04-12 03:34:09.366 18769-18769/com.example.tpv I/ERROR: Producto ID:3 : salchicha p/ asar : 3
2022-04-12 03:34:09.366 18769-18769/com.example.tpv I/ERROR: Producto ID:3 : tocino : 3
2022-04-12 03:34:09.367 18769-18769/com.example.tpv I/ERROR: Producto ID:3 : boneless : 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucione mi problema al cambiar de "var" a "val" la cantidad_extra en la data class MateriPrima y copiando el objeto con el nuevo valor. Si alguien tiene una explicación se los agradecería